# Unable to specify which response type is accepted when calling a Jersey api

Tags: xml, json, rest, jaxb, jersey

I have a Jersey api that was previously set up to respond with XML (JAXB marshalling, @Produces("application/xml")). I now want to add the ability to request responses in JSON format using the JAXB/JSON compatibilities.

I changed the argument to my @Produces annotation to be {"application/json", "application/xml"}, which sets JSON as the default response type. I then make the following calls to get a user by email using cUrl:

```
curl -k https://api.mywebservice.com/service/user/email/foo@bar.com
```

returns a JSON response as expected.

```
curl -k -H "accepts: application/xml" -H "content-type: application/xml" https://api.mywebservice.com/service/user/email/foo@bar.com
```

**also** produces a JSON response.

Of course the first thing I did was switch the annotation to be @Produces{"application/xml", "application/json"} and then could no longer get a JSON response, even if I specified one in the header.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The header is called `Accept`, hence you need to call:

```
curl -k -H "accept: application/xml" https://api.mywebservice.com/service/user/email/foo@bar.com
```

Also the `Content-Type` header is for specifying the media type of data sent to the server in a POST or PUT request, so you should just leave that one away for GET requests.

Comment: Man, I figured it was something little like that. Thanks a bunch!